# No data returned in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report I'm working on; last week it was returning results but when I fired it up this morning I was no longer getting anything. Checking the SQL query, I show that the table name is listed twice, for some reason:

```
 SELECT "WMS_TESTINFO"."RECORD_NAME"
 FROM   "TestEnv"."dbo"."WMS_TESTINFO" "WMS_TESTINFO"
```

Any thoughts on what could have broken? I've checked that the database is connected and my data is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table name is listed twice as Crystal Reports creates an alias for every table.

This Crystal generated SQL:

`FROM   "TestEnv"."dbo"."WMS_TESTINFO" "WMS_TESTINFO"`

Is in the format of:

`FROM DATABASE.OWNER.TABLENAME ALIAS`

This is normal for Crystal.

I would run that SQL in SSMS (remembering to remove all of the `"` first) to check that the data really is still there.

If it is, check that a filter hasn't been added to the report, via the `Select Expert` menu opton, to filter out all the data.

[image]

Lastly, go to `Database` > `Set Datasource Location` and re-apply the connection to ensure that the report is definitely pointing at the right location.

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with the server, but I'm marking this as best answer for being informative and well-written.